# How to display just the X latest input in Odoo graph?

Tags: graph, odoo

I'd like to know how to display the latest 10 inputs in odoo database in my graph.

Odoo display by default all the inputs, I want to limit this, any way to do that?

Comment: You can use domain to limit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve this issue by ovveride the `read_group` method of the **models.py** in my module. then I check the numbers of the rows that I want to get.